# ¿ How send data a linePlusBarWithFocusChart NVD3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to send a data to array values ​​of the linePlusBarWithFocusChart chart, create a function that allows me to do that

```
$scope.generatelinePlusBarWithFocusChart = function(values, name, date)
{
//Recibo 
//values= datos a graficar(Y)
//name = nombre de serie de graficos(KEY)
//date = fecha a graficar (X)

//Creo vector para guardar los datos
var line = []

//los datos se caragn sobre el array 
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    //Se convierte el la fecha llegada por parametro en milisegundos
    date_Value = Date.parse(date[i]);
    //Se agrega al aray line dos valores, X que sera la fecha, y Y que sera el valor
    line.push([date_Value,values[i]]);
}

//Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
//Envio los datos de a values, envio el nombre de la serie y los valores
$scope.data.push({
    values: line, //values - represents the array 
    key: name, //key  - the name of the series.
 });
};
```

But when they are sent I get the following error

```
Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I do not have the slightest idea

The graph saves the data as well

```
{ 
"key": "Price",
"values": [[1136005200000, 71.89], [1138683600000, 75.51], [1141102800000, 68.49], [1143781200000, 62.72], [1146369600000, 70.39], [1149048000000, 59.77], [1151640000000, 57.27], [1154318400000, 67.96], [1156996800000, 67.85], [1159588800000, 76.98], [1162270800000, 81.08], [1164862800000, 91.66], [1167541200000, 84.84], [1170219600000, 85.73], [1172638800000, 84.61], [1175313600000, 92.91], [1177905600000, 99.8], [1180584000000, 121.191], [1183176000000, 122.04], [1185854400000, 131.76], [1188532800000, 138.48], [1191124800000, 153.47], [1193803200000, 189.95], [1196398800000, 182.22], [1199077200000, 198.08], [1201755600000, 135.36], [1204261200000, 125.02], [1206936000000, 143.5], [1209528000000, 173.95], [1212206400000, 188.75], [1214798400000, 167.44], [1217476800000, 158.95], [1220155200000, 169.53], [1222747200000, 113.66], [1225425600000, 107.59], [1228021200000, 92.67], [1230699600000, 85.35], [1233378000000, 90.13], [1235797200000, 89.31], [1238472000000, 105.12], [1241064000000, 125.83], [1243742400000, 135.81], [1246334400000, 142.43], [1249012800000, 163.39], [1251691200000, 168.21], [1254283200000, 185.35], [1256961600000, 188.5], [1259557200000, 199.91], [1262235600000, 210.732], [1264914000000, 192.063], [1267333200000, 204.62], [1270008000000, 235.0], [1272600000000, 261.09], [1275278400000, 256.88], [1277870400000, 251.53], [1280548800000, 257.25], [1283227200000, 243.1], [1285819200000, 283.75], [1288497600000, 300.98], [1291093200000, 311.15], [1293771600000, 322.56], [1296450000000, 339.32], [1298869200000, 353.21], [1301544000000, 348.5075], [1304136000000, 350.13], [1306814400000, 347.83], [1309406400000, 335.67], [1312084800000, 390.48], [1314763200000, 384.83], [1317355200000, 381.32], [1320033600000, 404.78], [1322629200000, 382.2], [1325307600000, 405.0], [1327986000000, 456.48], [1330491600000, 542.44], [1333166400000, 599.55], [1335758400000, 583.98]]
}
```

I save the data in an array of 2 positions
The first being the date (value x) and the second the data to be plotted (value y)

The first being the date (value x) and the second the data to be plotted (value y), but I never called this function d3.js

```
function attrConstant() {
  this.setAttribute(name, value);
}
```

Thanks to who can help me

Comment: Show us the code that is looking for the width and x.

Comment: ok.. Thank @krillgar